# SSH Authentication Prompts Twice for Password When Using PAM with Google Authenticator

Tags: ssh, sshd, pam

I'm setting up two-factor authentication (2FA) on an Ubuntu server using `libpam-google-authenticator`. I've configured SSH to use PAM for authentication with the following `/etc/pam.d/sshd` configuration:

```bash
auth required pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
account required pam_unix.so
password required pam_unix.so
session required pam_unix.so
```

And here is my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration:

```bash
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods password,keyboard-interactive:pam
```

When I SSH into the server, I'm prompted twice for my password before it asks for the OTP from Google Authenticator. It seems like `pam_google_authenticator.so` is asking for the password and treating it as the OTP.

What I expect is that it should ask for my password once, and then for the OTP from Google Authenticator.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.